# How to use RegOpenKeyEx in Local System app?

Tags: c#, windows, winapi, registry

I have the problem with accessing `"HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run"`. Function returns result 2, that means "File not found". I'm pretty sure this happened because of Local System rights in application but don't know how to fix this.

```
int result = RegOpenKeyEx(registryHive, registrySubname, 0,STANDART_RIGHTS_READ | KEY_QUERY_VALUE | KEY_NOTIFY , out registryKey);
```

Any ideas?

UPD: I've checked this in application with current user rights and everything worked

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/185829/discussion-on-question-by-oleg-lylok-how-to-use-regopenkeyex-in-local-system-app).

Answer (score 0):

When running as the `LocalSystem` account, such as in a service, you can't use `RegOpenKeyEx()` to open the `HKEY_CURRENT_USER` hive of any user account other than `LocalSystem`. To open the HKCU hive of another user, you need to first impersonate that user, such as with [`ImpersonateLoggedOnUser()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/securitybaseapi/nf-securitybaseapi-impersonateloggedonuser), and then use [`RegOpenCurrentUser()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winreg/nf-winreg-regopencurrentuser).